# Setting up SSL on a local xampp/apache server

Tags: php, apache, ssl, https, xampp

I'm trying to access a Active Directory from my local webserver. To do this I'm using the latest version of xampp and a PHP script called [adLDAP](http://adldap.sourceforge.net/). If I understand things right, I need to enable SSL to access https URLs. I've tried to google it but with no luck :( Could anyone link a tutorial or explain to me how to install SSL on xampp/apache for windows 7 64bit? Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: When I navigate to \adLDAP\examples\authenticate.php this file redirects me to a https:// url. Firefox displays Access forbidden! Error 403 because I don't have SSL enabled.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Apache part - enabling you to open https://localhost/xyz

There is the config file xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf which contains all the ssl specific configuration. It's fairly well documented, so have a read of the comments and take look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/.
The files starts with `<IfModule ssl_module>`, so it only has an effect if the apache has been started with its mod_ssl module.

Open the file xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf in an editor and search for the line

```
#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

remove the hashmark, save the file and re-start the apache. The webserver should now start with xampp's basic/default ssl confguration; good enough for testing but you might want to read up a bit more about mod_ssl in the apache documentation.

---

PHP part - enabling adldap to use [ldap over ssl](http://adldap.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php?id=ldap_over_ssl)

adldap needs php's openssl extension to use "ldap over ssl" connections. The openssl extension ships as a dll with xampp. You must "tell" php to load this dll, e.g. by having an `extension=nameofmodule.dll` in your php.ini
Run

```
echo 'ini: ', get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');
```

It should show you which ini file your php installation uses (may differ between the php-apache-module and the php-cli version).
Open this file in an editor and search for

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

remove the semicolon, save the file and re-start the apache.

see also: http://docs.php.net/install.windows.extensions

Comment: the echo line gives this answer: C:\xampp\php\php.ini

but there is no ;extension=php_openssl.dll in this file. I checked the \php\ext folder aswell and there is no php_openssl.dll :\

Comment: Which version of xampp do you use?

Comment: Not sure if this info is helpfull, but:

phpinfo()

[openssl]
OpenSSL support: enabled -
OpenSSL Library Version: OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009 - 
OpenSSL Header Version: OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009 

[Phar]
...
Native OpenSSL support: enabled 

[PHP Variables]
...
_SERVER["OPENSSL_CONF"] C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf --

wow, this comment was messy :S wtb linebreak

Comment: I'm using XAMPP version 1.7.3

Comment: ok, then php_openssl is already enabled. Take a look at the first part of the revised answer.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help so far. I will get back to you when I've done some testing :)

Comment: stupid question: openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt <- where do i type this command? tried cmd and openssl.exe :S

Comment: There's a openssl.exe in xampp/apache/bin. And there's most likely a question (or two) related to how to create certificates under win32 either here on stackoverflow or on http://serverfault.com

Comment: o m g. Looks like https worked when i reinstalled xampp and used the default htdocs folder. :P

Comment: @VolkerK, thanks, this post helped a lot. For future searchers, the `extension=php_openssl.dll` line is actually missing from `php.ini` on XMAPP 1.7.4...but that is an easy fix.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that OpenSSL is compiled and enabled in php 5.3 of XAMPP 1.7.2 and so no longer requires a separate extension dll.

However, you STILL need to enable it in your PHP.ini file the line `extension=php_openssl.dll`

Answer (score 4):

I did most of the suggested stuff here, still didnt work. Tried this and it worked:
Open your **XAMPP Control Panel**, locate the **Config** button for the **Apache module**. Click on the Config button and Select **PHP (php.ini)**. Open with any text editor and remove the semi-column before **php_openssl**. Save and Restart Apache. That should do!

Answer (score 2):

You can enable SSL on XAMPP by creating self signed certificates and then installing those certificates. Type the below commands to generate and move the certificates to ssl folders.

> openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024
>
> openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
>
> cp server.key server.key.org
>
> openssl rsa -in server.key.org -out server.key
>
> openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
>
> cp server.crt /opt/lampp/etc/ssl.crt/domainname.crt
>
> cp server.key /opt/lampp/etc/ssl.key/domainname.key

(Use sudo with each command if you are not the super user)

Now, Check that mod_ssl is enabled in [XAMPP_HOME]/etc/httpd.conf:

> LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

Add a virtual host, in this example "localhost.domainname.com" by editing [XAMPP_HOME]/etc/extra/httpd-ssl.conf as follows:

```
<virtualhost 127.0.1.4:443>
    ServerName localhost.domainname.com
    ServerAlias localhost.domainname.com *.localhost.domainname.com
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost

    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/"

    DirectoryIndex index.php

    ErrorLog /opt/lampp/logs/domainname.local.error.log
    CustomLog /opt/lampp/logs/domainname.local.access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile /opt/lampp/etc/ssl.crt/domainname.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/lampp/etc/ssl.key/domainname.key

    <directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </directory>
    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
</virtualhost>
```

Add the following entry to /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.1.4 localhost.domainname.com
```

Now, try installing the certificate/ try importing certificate to browser. I have checked this and this worked on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I have been through all the answers and tutorials over the internet but here are the **basic steps** to **enable** SSL (**https**) on localhost with **XAMPP**:

## Required:

1. Run -> "C:\xampp\apache\makecert.bat" (double-click on windows)
   Fill passowords of your choice, hit Enter for everything BUT define "localhost"!!! Be careful when asked here:

   *Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:**localhost***

   (Certificates are issued per domain name zone only!)
2. Restart apache
3. Chrome -> Settings -> Search "Certificate" -> Manage Certificates -> Trusted Root Certification Authorities -> Import -> "C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.crt\server.crt" -> Must Ask "YES" for confirmation!
4. https://localhost/testssl.php -> [OK, Now Green!] (any html test file)

## Optional: (if above doesn't work, do more of these steps)

1. Run XAMPP As admin (Start -> XAMPP -> right-click -> Run As Administrator)
2. XAMPP -> Apache -> Config -> httpd.conf ("C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf")

   LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so (remove # form the start of line)
3. XAMPP -> Apache -> Config -> php.ini ("C:\xampp\php\php.ini")

   extension=php_openssl.dll (remove ; from the start of line)
4. Restart apache and chrome!

> Check any problems or the status of your certificate:
>
> Chrome -> F12 -> Security -> View Certificate

Answer (score 0):

I did all of the suggested stuff here and my code still did not work because I was using `curl`

If you are using `curl` in the php file, curl seems to reject all ssl traffic by default. A quick-fix that worked for me was to add:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

before calling:

```
 curl_exec():
```

in the php file.

I believe that this disables all verification of SSL certificates.

Comment: ... and by disabling the verification of the certificates, you leave the door open to potential MITM attacks, which SSL/TLS otherwise aims to protect against. DON'T DO THIS!

Comment: Yup. I should have drawn more attention to this in the answer. Only do this if you aren't working on anything important. I use it on localhost to access websites that I personally programmed.

Answer (score 0):

To enable this setting in Chrome:

```
chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost
```

Just put this into URL input and enable it. Restart browser. SSL server.crt must be imported in browser in "Trusted Root Certification Authorities".

https started working as expected.