# How do I use https (SSL) in XAMPP while using virtual hosts

Tags: apache, ssl, https, xampp, virtualhost

I am writing a php app on my local machine and would like to test to see if SSL is working. Bear with me because this is the first time I've ever used SSL.

So far this is what I've done:

1. Created a SSL Certificate. I followed the first part of this [this](http://robsnotebook.com/xampp-ssl-encrypt-passwords) tutorial to create the certificate.
2. I imported the `server.crt` file into chrome.
3. Removed the semicolon in front of `;extension=php_openssl.dll` in `php.ini` ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2643598/1043817))
4. Edited my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file based on [this](http://www.leonardaustin.com/technical/how-to-enable-ssl-on-xampp-with-vhosts) page. The relevant section of that file is below. This is the full file: http://pastebin.com/k6Jh2eR6

   > ```
   > <VirtualHost *>
   >     DocumentRoot "C:\Users\user_name\Documents\project_one"
   >     ServerName project_one.localhost
   >     SSLEngine on
   >     SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
   >     SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
   >     <Directory "C:\Users\user_name\Documents\project_one">
   >         AllowOverride All
   >         Order allow,deny
   >         Allow from all
   >     </Directory>
   > </VirtualHost>
   > ```

I would usually access my project by typing in `http://project_one.localhost`

**When trying to access my project by typing `https://project_one.localhost` into chrome I automatically get forwarded to `https://project_one.localhost/xampp/` (as if XAMPP doesn't recognize `https://project_one.localhost` as a subdomain at all and treats it as if I'm typing in `https://localhost`) Any idea where I'm screwing up?**

NOTE:

- `LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so` was uncommented in `httpd.conf` file

Comment: Hi, were you able to get a solution to this problem? Just a little observation, although this is coming at a late hour, but I couldn't locate this line "SSLRequireSSL" in your config file.

Comment: I think you need to generate ssl certificate with server name 'project_one.localhost'

Comment: @user28864 - see [How do I edit a self signed certificate created using openssl xampp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019957/how-do-i-edit-a-self-signed-certificate-created-using-openssl-xampp) for instructions on creating a certificate with multiple DNS names (like `localhost`, `localhost.localdomain` and `project_one.localhost`) in the Subject Alternate Names (SANs).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

SSL, of the `HTTPS://url.here/` variety, is entirely handled by Apache and has nothing to do with PHP, or any of PHP's extensions/modules, or any php.ini settings.

A typical SSL Enabled VirtualHost looks like this and contains at least these parts...

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/WampDeveloper/Websites/www.example.com/webroot"
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    SSLEngine On

    SSLCertificateFile "C:/WampDeveloper/Websites/www.example.com/certs/public.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/WampDeveloper/Websites/www.example.com/certs/private.key"

    <Directory "C:/WampDeveloper/Websites/www.example.com/webroot">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

(The paths above are from my WampDeveloper Pro set up, Xampp's will be slightly different)

Your `<VirtualHost *>` line is faulty. It needs a port number, which is always 443 for an HTTPS:// URL, in combination with either an IP address or a star before it. And if using a star, also a `NameVirtualHost *:443` line...

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\user_name\Documents\project_one"
    ServerName project_one.localhost
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
    <Directory "C:\Users\user_name\Documents\project_one">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\user_name\Documents\project_two"
    ServerName project_two.localhost
    <Directory "C:\Users\user_name\Documents\project_two">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: yes. i followed your instructions and its running. thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Here is simple step.

1. Go to **C:\xampp\apache\conf**

Open **httpd.conf**

And enable the **ssl extensions** (**Remove # from line**)

```html
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

2. Go to **C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra**

Open **httpd-vhosts.conf**

Add new virtual hosts or edit existing

```html
<VirtualHost *:443>   
 DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/PROJECTNAME" 
 ServerName www.pl.f24sdev.com
 <Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/PROJECTPATH>
  AllowOverride All
  Order Deny,Allow   
  Allow from all  
 </Directory>
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
 SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"   
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 7):

This may be an old question, but i am putting my answer here anyway for future reference

i'm **Using XAMPP 3.2.1, Compiled May,7 2013**

to enable `VirtualHost` with `SSL` at the same time here is what i did. (I'm using windows 7)

1. your windows `HOST` file must already be setup
2. Go to `httpd-ssl.conf` located at `xampp\apache\conf\extra`

I just copied the `_default_` `virtualhost` and added my config. I removed all comments for shorter one and pasted this just below the default `virtualHost` just change the `DocumentRoot` and `servername` then Restart apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "***path/to/your/project}***"
    ServerName ***yourdomain***
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ErrorLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
    TransferLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "C:/xampp/apache/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    CustomLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/ssl_request.log" \
              "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: what should be set in ServerName? localhost?

Comment: @Saurabh Its what you added on your HOSTS file to access the page.

Answer (score 4):

Which version of Apache are you using ? NameVirtualHost is not available in 2.4 version.

Uncomment the line `Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` in httpd.conf and add the following contents (fix the paths according to xampp's path). This will enable `https://localhost`

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
Listen 443
AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crlss phrase on stdout.
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:E:/PROGRA\~1/AMPPS/apache/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
Mutex default

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "E:/Program Files/AMPPS/www"
ServerName localhost:443
ServerAdmin you@127.0.0.1
ErrorLog "E:/Program Files/AMPPS/apache/logs/ssl_error.log"
TransferLog "E:/Program Files/AMPPS/apache/logs/ssl_access.log"
SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
SSLCertificateFile "E:/Program Files/AMPPS/apache/conf/ssl_crt/server.crt"
#SSLCertificateFile "E:/Program Files/AMPPS/apache/conf/server-dsa.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "E:/Program Files/AMPPS/apache/conf/ssl_key/server.key"
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "E:/Program Files/AMPPS/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
CustomLog "E:/Program Files/AMPPS/apache/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

If you want other domain like project_one.localhost have secured http connection then add the following virtualhost in httpd.conf or httpd-vhosts.conf(must be included in httpd.conf)

```
<IfModule ssl_module>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
<Directory "e:/program files/ampps/www/project_one.localhost">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
allow from All
</Directory>
ServerName project_one.localhost
ServerAlias project_one.localhost
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "e:/program files/ampps/www/project_one.localhost/cgi-bin/"
DocumentRoot "e:/program files/ampps/www/project_one.localhost"
SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
SSLCertificateFile "E:\Program Files\AMPPS/apache/conf/ssl_crt/project_one.localhost.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "E:\Program Files\AMPPS/apache/conf/ssl_key/project_one.localhost.key"
ErrorLog "E:/Program Files/AMPPS/apache/logs/project_one.localhost_ssl_error.log"
TransferLog "E:/Program Files/AMPPS/apache/logs/project_one.localhost_ssl_access.log"
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "e:/program files/ampps/www/project_one.localhost/cgi-bin/">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
CustomLog "E:/Program Files/AMPPS/apache/logs/project_one.localhost_ssl_request.log" \
    "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**Note : You will have to add an entry in hosts file** `127.0.0.1 project_one.localhost`

Comment: I am running XAMPP version 1.8.0. according to http://www.apachefriends.org/en/news-article,196165.html I am running Apache 2.4.2, is NameVirtualHost supported in that version?

Comment: `The NameVirtualHost directive no longer has any effect, other than to emit a warning. Any address/port combination appearing in multiple virtual hosts is implicitly treated as a name-based virtual host.` - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Answer (score 0):

```
# to use ssl

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/httpsProject"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"

    <Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/httpsProject"
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all grated
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).