# Configure SSL for XAMPP

Tags: apache, ssl, xampp

I have a **wordpress** project that uses SSL and I want to run it on XAMPP.

I modified my httpd-vhosts.conf and my httpd-ssl.conf to create a virtual host for this particular wordpress project.

Here is my httpd-vhosts.conf file contents

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/wordpresssoftd"
    ServerName mysite.local
    ServerAlias mysite.local
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl.crt/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl.key/server.key 
    <Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/wordpresssoftd">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

wordpresssoftd contains my project files.

I have also renamed the document root in httpd-ssl.conf.

When I run the website, the CSS and JS files are not loaded, but the index page of the wordpress site is served up without the CSS and JS.

[image: I have added screenshot from Google Chrome Web Inspector]

I have already checked these links to no avail

[Enabling SSL with XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801425/enabling-ssl-with-xampp)

[Setting up SSL on a local xampp/apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643462/setting-up-ssl-on-a-local-xampp-apache-server)

[How do I use https (SSL) in XAMPP while using virtual hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430574/how-do-i-use-https-ssl-in-xampp-while-using-virtual-hosts)

http://www.leonardaustin.com/blog/technical/how-to-enable-ssl-on-xampp-with-vhosts/

https://jaswanttak.wordpress.com/2010/04/15/configure-ssl-on-xampp-and-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Everything was set correctly.

Instead of accessing my site using

```
https://localhost/wordpresssoftd
```

I used

```
https://localhost
```