# Local development of geolocation chrome 50+

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, geolocation

I am developing a website which require the use of the navigator.geolocation object through a local development environment on MACOSX. I am using Chrome 53. Considering geolocation is blocked on anything that isn't HTTPS how am I suppose to develop my website locally? The Google Developers site quotes:

> Does this affect local development?
>
> It should not, localhost has been declared as "potentially secure" in
>   the spec and in our case geolocation requests served at the top level
>   over localhost will still work.

Here's what I am seeing:

[Geolocation console warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhV38.png)

Any ideas? (aside from switch browser)

Comment: You can use `about://flags` instead of passing commanding arguments.
Here is how to do it on Android's Google Chrome.

Answer (score 9):

`http://localhost` is treated as a secure origin, so you don't need to do anything, the Geolocation will work.

If you're using another hostname that points to the localhost (Ex: `http://mysite.test`) then you should run chrome from the command line with the following option: `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://mysite.test"`.

**Example**

```
google-chrome --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://yoursite.test"
```

More details on [Deprecating Powerful Features on Insecure Origins](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins)

Comment: on my mac i didnt have the `google-chrome` symlink so instead i used `open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app' --args --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://yoursite.test"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `file:` protocol. Launch chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag set, see [Jquery load() only working in firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996001/jquery-load-only-working-in-firefox/32996188?s=1|2.0351#32996188). At `Settings` select `Content settings`, scroll to `Location`, select `Ask when a site tries to track your physical location (recommended)`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is to set VirtualHost in XAMPP to use the SSL Engine. This question has already been answered here: [How do I use https (SSL) in XAMPP while using virtual hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430574/how-do-i-use-https-ssl-in-xampp-while-using-virtual-hosts)

This then allows the Geolocation to run through HTTPS on a local development environment using XAMPP.