# How can I make Geolocation API function working on localhost file://?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have this basic code to retrieve latitude and longitude with Geolocation API :

**showmap.html**

```
<button  onclick="getLocation()">Find me </button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/geolocation.js"></script>
```

**js/geolocation.js**

```
function getLocation() {

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by your browser. Please update your browser. Visit Help Center.");
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude =  position.coords.longitude;

  console.log("Latitude : " + latitude + "<br> Longitude :" + longitude);
}
```

When I click on the button I receive this error in the console

```
SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified showmap.html:72
    _sendMessage file:///home/user/Desktop/Projects/showmap.html:72
    call file:///home/user/Desktop/Projects/showmap.html:64
    getCurrentPosition file:///home/user/Desktop/Projects/showmap.html:16
    getLocation file:///home/user/Desktop/Projects/js/geolocation.js:4
    onclick file:///home/user/Desktop/Projects/showmap.html:1
    fireMouseEvent resource://devtools/server/actors/emulation/touch-simulator.js:290
    dispatchMouseEvents resource://devtools/server/actors/emulation/touch-simulator.js:264
```

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this issue. Is this not working because I'm in `file://` ?

Comment: That is the incorrect protocol.

Comment: Is this is an answer to your question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40295830/local-development-of-geolocation-chrome-50 .The code you have given working perfectly on the test

Comment: @StackSlave : Interesting. What do you mean? Could you elaborate please? Thanks

Comment: @marcelo : According to the conversations in that thread file:// should not be a problem since it's ran from localhost, yes?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Resource_URLs

Comment: @SaturnConjuction No, `file://` is not a hosted server, it is the filesystem of your local machine. When interacting with a server, you use `http(s)://` protocol. See guest271314's answer in the dup proposed by marcelo.

Comment: @StackSlave : I get it. Will run ngrok.

Comment: You also probably don't have access to the Client's filesystem.

Comment: @StackSlave: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `file:` to work with Geolocation Api, run `ngrok` and use the `https` url to host your HTML app. No need for PHP or backend language like Python, you can generate a local tunnel using your credentials.

This assumes you have ngrok installed and that you are running Ubuntu.

Open terminal and run :

```
ngrok http -auth="user:password" file:///path/to/your/HTML/project
```

Reference : 
Serving local directories with ngrok's built-in fileserver 
https://ngrok.com/docs