# geoLocation only works via the console?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn Geolocation API in javascript but the simplest lines of code do not seem to work. If i paste them in the console though, they work normally.
Geolocation only works if i paste the code directly into the console, but not if I try to run it from a text editor. I use VS Code and checked all Windows settings and Firefox settings yet nothing seems to fix the problem

```
const geo = navigator.geolocation;

const position = ()=>{
    console.log("OK");
}

geo.getCurrentPosition(position);
```

Comment: Are you running it on a https server?

Comment: geolocation in web page only works on secure site

Comment: im running it in a common file no localhost, no https server

Comment: It may not be an exact fit, but does this answer your question? [How can I make Geolocation API function working on localhost file://?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59675712/how-can-i-make-geolocation-api-function-working-on-localhost-file)