# SSL certificate integration in a Yii web application

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I would like to know what are the steps to be done for integrating an SSL cerificate to my website . I created a certificate from http://www.cert-depot.com/ for testing and got a .pam file and .pfx file. Where should I add this files to integrate it with my php YII web application. In my local Iam using xampp Apache as server. WHat should I do next ??

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801425/enabling-ssl-with-xampp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643462/setting-up-ssl-on-a-local-xampp-apache-server

Comment: @dency-g-b 
I got the web page that accessed as https. But I am accessing phpmyadmin it says "Your connection to localhost is encrypted with 128-bit encryption. However, this page includes other resources which are not secure. These resources can be viewed by others while in transit, and can be modified by an attacker to change the behavoiur of the page.The connection uses TLS1.2 ." I used the makecert in apache folder and made some new certs. and also imported them to my webbrowser. how can I resolve it?