# Slimframework 2 problem - URL and Array in Array json Outp

Tags: json, frameworks, slim

**Problem 1**
This is my nested array code

```
        $product = $db->query("SELECT * FROM product")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        return $response
        ->withStatus(200)
        ->withHeader("Content-Type", 'application/json')
        ->withJson($product);
```

output

```
[
{
"product_id": "1",
"product_name": "Ahmet",
"product_price": "10.00",
"product_status": "",
"product_slung": "",
"product_property": "{\"p1\": 1, \"p2\": \"Leanne Graham\", \"o3\": \"Bret\"}",
"product_createdtime": "{\"date\": \"06.05.2020\", \"time\": \"23:19\"}"
}
]
```

{\"p1\": 1, \"p2\": \"Leanne Graham\", \"o3\": \"Bret\"} 
adding \ problem

**Problem 2**
No problem when you enter this way
`http://as.localhost/api/product/`
When I enter this way, I get such an error
`http://as.localhost/api/product`
"Page Not Found"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting up SSL on a local xampp/apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643462/setting-up-ssl-on-a-local-xampp-apache-server)

Comment: I don't think the problem is due to SSL, but I'll try.

Comment: if its not that your localhost isnt configured for SSL, or that you havent mapped the SSL port (not just port 80) to that localhost subdomain, then thats critical information to include above, with proof on how other https pages on SAME domain do work.

Comment: i am sorry, my problem is not solved

Comment: Please add route definition for `/api/product`. Also, clarify problem 1 by adding the value of `$product` and expected json output.

Comment: Problem 1 
```[
{
"product_id": "1",
"product_name": "Ahmet",
"product_price": "10.00",
"product_status": "",
"product_slung": "",
"product_property": "{\"p1\": 1, \"p2\": \"Leanne Graham\", \"o3\": \"Bret\"}",
"product_createdtime": "{\"date\": \"06.05.2020\", \"time\": \"23:19\"}"
}
]
"product_property": "{\"p1\": 1, \"p2\": \"Leanne Graham\", \"o3\": \"Bret\"}",
 ```
backslash problem
      
Problem 2 Route Code
```$app->get('/product/', function ($request, $response, $id) {
 
// code
});
```
@Nima

Comment: Please show us your route for `api/product`.